# inappropriate deploy Scrapy proxies

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, web-scraping, scrapy

I got a error message, when I am scraping a profile. I assume I use my proxy wrong. But what is the main error here? Can you guys help

> 2017-06-15 21:35:17 [scrapy.proxies] INFO: Removing failed proxy
>   , 12 proxies left 2017-06-15
>   21:35:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading https://www.linkedin.com/in/jiajie-jacky-fan-80920083/> Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/jiajiefan/data_mining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py",
>   line 1299, in _inlineCallbacks
>       result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)   File "/Users/jiajiefan/data_mining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py",
>   line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
>       return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)   File "/Users/jiajiefan/data_mining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py",
>   line 43, in process_request
>       defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))   File
>   "/Users/jiajiefan/data_mining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/utils/defer.py",
>   line 45, in mustbe_deferred
>       result = f(*args, **kw)   File "/Users/jiajiefan/data_mining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/**init**.py",
>   line 65, in download_request
>       return handler.download_request(request, spider)   File "/Users/jiajiefan/data_mining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py",
>   line 63, in download_request
>       return agent.download_request(request)   File "/Users/jiajiefan/data_mining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py",
>   line 272, in download_request
>       agent = self._get_agent(request, timeout)   File "/Users/jiajiefan/data_mining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py",
>   line 252, in _get_agent
>       _, _, proxyHost, proxyPort, proxyParams = _parse(proxy)   File "/Users/jiajiefan/data_mining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/core/downloader/webclient.py", line 37, in _parse
>       return _parsed_url_args(parsed)   File "/Users/jiajiefan/data_mining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/core/downloader/webclient.py", line 21, in _parsed_url_args
>       port = parsed.port   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py",
>   line 113, in port
>       port = int(port, 10) ValueError: invalid literal fo
>   r int() with base 10: '178.32.255.199'

Answer (score 0):

Proxy should has address with 'http', etc:

```
rq.meta['proxy'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8123'
```

Comment: I tried it, and it does not work. The result showed the proxies are unusable.